# What linearization algorithm does Ruby use for Mixins?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, it is possible for modules to include other modules, as a form of multiple inheritance. To test this out, I wrote the following program, based on an example from an article on C3 linearization:

```
module O
  def doIt()
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "O"
  end
end

module F
  include O
  def doIt()
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "F"
  end
end

module E
  include O
  def doIt()
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "E"
  end
end

module D
  include O
  def doIt()
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "D"
  end
end

module C
  include F
  include D
  def doIt()
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "C"
  end
end

module B
  include E
  include D
  def doIt()
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "B"
  end
end

class A
  include C
  include B
  def doIt()
    super if defined?(super)
    puts "A"
  end
end

A.new.doIt
```

Which (on Ruby 1.9.3) outputs:

```
O
F
E
D
C
B
A
```

How does Ruby determine method resolution order in this case?

Comment: by the order of declaration - `include D; include E` is _not_ like `include E; include D`

Comment: @UriAgassi My apologies, the declaration order was wrong when I originally posted it (I copied a Python example, and precedence order is reversed between Python and Ruby). It should now reflect the example from the C3 article.

Comment: ...and that answers your question - the resolution order is the declaration order (the last implementation added is the first method run...)

Comment: @UriAgassi Not quite. If I change the include order slightly (swap the orders round in C, D, and A), then the order becomes OEDBFCA. Previously, it had decided that B and C (A's direct ancestors) should have higher priority than any other ancestors, but now F has higher priority than B. And why are immediate ancestors higher priority than more distant ancestors? "latest wins" would suggest that all C's ancestors had higher priority than B's, and yet in the posted version B has higher priority than C's ancestors.

Answer (score 3):

I've written an article that describes the algorithm here: http://norswap.com/ruby-module-linearization/

Pasting in the most important bits:

```
Include = Struct.new :mod
Prepend = Struct.new :mod

# Returns the ancestry chain of `mod`, given the environment `env`.
#
# No distinctions are made between classes and modules: where a class extends
# another class, that class is treated as the first included module.
#
# params:
# - mod: Symbol
#   Represents a module.
# - env: Map<Symbol, Array<Include|Prepend>>
#   Maps modules to inclusions, in order of apperance.

def ancestors (mod, env)
  chain = [mod]
  includes = env[mod]
  includes.each { |it| insert(mod, it, env, chain) }
  chain
end


def insert (mod, inclusion, env, chain)
  i = inclusion.is_a?(Prepend) ? 0 : 1
  ancestors(inclusion.mod, env).each do |it|
    raise ArgumentError('cyclic include detected') if it == mod
    j = chain.find_index it
    if not j.nil?
      i = j + 1 if j >= i
      next
    end
    chain.insert(i, it)
    i += 1
  end
end
```

> Let's try to get some intuition in there. Let's start with some
>   observations:
>
> - If B is included after A, B take precedence over A.
> - If B extends or includes A, B takes precedences over A.
> - When including a module X, the algorithm tries to maintain the ordering of the ancestor chain of X.
> - If there is a conflict of ordering, the algorithm always favors the ordering of modules that were included earlier.
>
> The last point highlight the most unintuitive thing about the
>   algorithm: modules included later take precedence, but when
>   considering conflicts of ordering, it's modules included earlier that
>   win!
>
> The reason is that in Ruby, we may include a module in another at any
>   time. Ruby never reorders modules in the ancestor chain, but has no
>   problem inserting modules in between existing modules. This does make
>   sense, but leads to puzzling linearization behaviour.
>
> Making module included earlier take precedence would solve the
>   problem. However when we include a module in another at runtime, we
>   usually would like it to take precedence on previously included
>   modules!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. Looking at [the Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1b6aa03eb91c13a78d6a13158f04a5930fc9c3ef/class.c#L823), the algorithm seems to be:

> When including module `M` into class `A`, append all of `M`'s ancestors onto `A`'s ancestor chain, excluding any that are already present in `A`'s ancestor chain.

I believe this is equivalent to [Scala's MRO](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html#algorithm), or the "naive" MRO described in [PEP 253](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0253/) (which was never actually implemented in Python).